# Black screen & flickering mouse cursor

Tags: windows-8.1, black-screen-of-death

I recently uninstalled uxstyle and rebooted my PC, and now when you would normally see the login screen, the screen is black, moving the mouse causes it to flicker, and the network icon blinks once every couple seconds.

Some background info: I installed the Windows 10 transformation pack a while ago. I decided to remove it, but had forgotten how. I'm pretty sure I did it wrong by removing uxstyle, I think I was supposed to open the transformation pack and uninstall from there, so it's possible that some files are still patched by the transformation pack and that I need originals, but I'm unsure which files or if this is even the case.

I am running Windows 8.1 on a desktop that requires a graphics card (no integrated graphics)

I have tried the following things:

- Boot into safe mode. Same black screen and flickering mouse cursor. The words "Safe Mode" in each corner flicker when I move the mouse as well.
- Run SFC through system repair. It said that it found some corrupt files it could not repair, but that it didn't log anything because it was an offline SFC.
- Run a system restore. There was only one restore point, and after attempting restore it said that it could not restore because it couldn't copy a directory from the source or something. Then Windows decided to delete the restore point, so now I have no restore points.
- Run startup repair. Did nothing.
- Boot in low resolution mode. Did nothing.
- Run remote desktop. It opens, shows the black screen, then disconnects.
- Run TeamViewer. It does not connect but says my desktop is online.
- Run VNC. It connects but I just get the same black screen. I can move the cursor but it still flickers.

FTP also works. It's like everything seems to be working but the graphics just aren't working. I can't open the task manager using Ctrl+Alt+Del or Ctrl+Shift+ESC.

Any ideas? I'd really like to avoid a reset/refresh. Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is dated. Where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Iason Nope. Reinstalled windows. Sorry man.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, no worries. Hopefully someone has a working solution and posts his answer here...before I resort to reinstalling :-)